# Cookie not set, using curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I currently learning to web scraping an asynchronous website. First, I need to get the cookie. I'm using the code below to save the cookie to a txt file. But it not save the cookie when I run it. When I access the file, it's empty. I don't know where my problem is, because you know I still a noob in this thing. Hope you guys can answer it. Thanks for your time.

```
$cookie_file_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Is it possible the site doesn't *set* any cookies until you do something like issue a login?

Comment: I think it set, because I can retrieve all the data from website without login. And the response header contain set cookie

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, url);` `url` isn't a variable, is it a constant?`

Comment: @BOBBYIRAWAN If a login isn't required, you might not need cookies at all.

Comment: Really, what you want to do is load the DOM so you can query it. A quick search led me to https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php (Basically, you want what BeautifulSoup does, I think.)

Comment: @pokeybit nope, I just change it to url. Should I give the url?

Comment: I think the cookie set in hidden place, like in javascript. Any idea how to locate it in the website? And the website I want to scrap is async